# Anti-theft against smart thieves

Tags: android, security

### 1. Summary

I don't find anti-theft Android application, that would work against thieves:

1. that can install new ROM,
2. that can to make Hard Reset.

### 2. Expected behavior

#### 1. Requirements

1. Not a big price; ideally, if gratis;
2. Android 5.1.1 compatible;
3. User can get location of smartphone, use remote access;
4. Blocking smartphone and notice to another phone, if SIM card changing;
5. Protection, if thief install a new ROM (for example, Anti-Theft disallow USB debugging and entering in Recovery mode);
6. Anti-Theft not deleted, if thief make hard reset/factory reset;
7. Autostart by smartphone start;
8. Not killing program process, if user use task killers;
9. Not attracting attention is the name of the program in lists of programs; ideally — possibility of custom name.

#### 2. Desirable requirements

1. Active development;
2. Notice with smartphone location to another phone before Anti-Theft deleting;
3. Not attracting attention is the name of the process in process managers; ideally — possibility of custom name.
4. Remote access to front camera photo and audio of smartphone.

### 3. Do not offer

1. Please, do not offer applications with big price as [**Reptilicus**](https://reptilicus.net/), [**Cerberus**](https://www.cerberusapp.com/home/en), [**Android Monitor**](http://monitor-android.ru/).
2. Please, do not offer applications, that not protect smartphone, if theft install new firmware or make hard reset (most programs that I tried).